# NodeJS Multiple Async Requests

Tags: node.js

I have the following code. It simulates time-intensive requests. I would expect NodeJS to process an "unlimited" amount of requests at once. Instead of it, it can't process more than two requests at a time. What should I do to convince NodeJS to process multiple requests at once?

```js
const http = require('http');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function response() {
    await sleep(10000);
    return '';
}

http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
    console.log('Request start...');
    const html = await response();
    console.log('Request end...');
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

```sh
$ node server.js
Request start...
Request start...
Request end...
Request start...
Request end...
Request end...
Request start...
Request start...
Request end...
...
```

I run NodeJS on macOS Mojave.

```sh
$ node -v
v14.11.0
```

Comment: What is the source of the requests?  Are they coming from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node ***is*** actually processing all of your requests simultaneously. The results come down to your method of "testing", and I'm assuming the following points are relevant to the conditions of your method:

**If you are testing via a browser:**

- Browsers have limitations on the number of HTTP connections you can open.
- Other 'smart features' of browsers can manipulate requests, such as "stalling" certain requests to a single host in Chrome.
- Most (if not all) modern browsers automatically request a favicon.ico in a second (separate) HTTP request to a host. (This could explain the initial two requests consecutively logged.)

An example of a bad test scenario in this case: Opening multiple tabs in a browser, and sending a request from each in quick succession.

**Observing the truth:**

There are various methods by which you can accurately test with multiple simultaneous requests, but here are a couple of simple options:

**1. Open a number of terminal instances and send a request from each:**

Bash

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

(or in one Bash instance:)

```
curl http://localhost:3000 & curl http://localhost:3000 & curl http://localhost:3000 & curl http://localhost:3000
```

PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:3000
```

**2. Request via one Chrome tab, repeatedly refreshing.**

I also modified your snippet to help indicate the request/response pairs:

```
const http = require('http');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function response() {
    await sleep(10000);
    return '';
}

let i = 1;
http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
    let j = i;
    i++;

    console.log('Request start...', j);
    const html = await response();
    console.log('Request end...', j);
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hello @Ryan! Thank you for your help. I sent test requests via multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari), so there wasn't a problem. I found the problem is somewhere in my PHP script or setting - I will investigate it tomorrow. In this case, I use a PHP script to curl headless Chrome in NodeJS.